# What is the big O for Hash look up if the keys were strings

Tags: string, hashmap, big-o, hashtable

Big O for hash table look ups can be : O(1) - while using array implementations O(log n) - while using binary tree implementations , where n is the number of entries in the hash table.

If they keys in the hash are strings of length m , wouldn't the the run time complexity be

O(m) or O(mlog n) ? (since there are m compares for every look up)

Or is it still O(1) and O(logn)

Comment: Count on Java to switch to a binary tree to handle a Hash Map. Look, your information is severely edge case based. In general, hash maps are O(1) for find operations. In some ridiculously rare edge cases, it may get worse *only* if the Hash Map is actually replaced with something else. A binary tree is not a hash map, and so the implementation has been altered at that point to something else. As for your string length m assertion, yes, that does happen however O(k) is considered to be O(1).

Comment: Also, this depends on how the hash function is implemented for a string. The developers may have decided e.g. to only hash the first or last 8 characters of the string, or they may have a transient member which stores the last hash of the string (since strings are immutable). Hash functions are supposed to be quick, which is why the time complexity of a hash table generally ignores the complexity of the hash function.